# Sorting ArrayList by specific value

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a way I can sort my teams arraylist by the number of points that team has, so whichever team has the highest points is first, and so on, please dont use comperator, because I don't understand how to use that, here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class team {
    public int teamNum;
    public int points = 0;
    public team(int x) {
       this.teamNum = x;
    }
    public team(int x,int y) {
        this.teamNum = x;
        this.points = y;
    }
}


public class Problem9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Test9.txt"));
    ArrayList<team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter=0;

    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
            boolean found = false;
            String[] split = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);

            if (!(n1 == 0 && n2 == 0)) {
                if (counter<1) teams.add(new team(n1));
                for (int i=0; i<teams.size(); i++) {
                    if (teams.get(i).teamNum == n1) {
                       teams.get(i).points+=n2;
                       found = true;
                    }
                }
            if (!found) {
                teams.add(new team(n1, n2));
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
    for (int k=0; k<teams.size(); k++)
        System.out.println(teams.get(k).teamNum + " " +  teams.get(k).points);
     }    
}
```

Comment: Asking not to use a library function is not a good way to ingratiate yourself to those helping you. Instead if you wanted help understanding it, we would be much more willing to help.

Comment: A `Comparator` is a something that compares measurable things. In other words, it's just a fancy way of saying "sort function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do sorting on a custom data type :

1. use Comparator
2. use Comparable

**Using Comparable**

```
class team implements Comparable<team> {
    public int teamNum;
    public int points = 0;
    public team(int x) {
       this.teamNum = x;
    }
    public team(int x,int y) {
        this.teamNum = x;
        this.points = y;
    }

    public int compareTo(team t1){
     return t1.points - this.points;
    }
}
```

Now use `Collections.sort()` on the `arraylist`, which would sort it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with @sschale, you can't run away from certain methods or libraries just because you do not know how to use it and hence do not want to use it. To help you out I will give you a much simplified form of comparator implementation here:

```
//Place this between class team and public class Problem9
static class rankcomparator implements Comparator<Team> {
    @Override //need to override
    public int compare(Team lhs, Team rhs) {
        return -compare(lhs.points, rhs.points); //if descending order
        //return compare(lhs.points, rhs.points); //if ascending order
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Add this code inside public class Problem9 ...
    Collections.sort(teams, new rankcomparator());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really need to learn how a `Comparator` and the `Comparable` interface work. I recommend [this tutorial on `Comparator` usage](https://caveofprogramming.com/java-collections-framework/sorting-lists-using-comparators-java-collections-framework-video-tutorial-part-7.html) and [this tutorial on using natural ordering through the `Comparable` interface](https://caveofprogramming.com/java-collections-framework/natural-order-comparable-collection-java-collections-framework-video-tutorial-part-8.html).

Concerning the issue at hand: just add a `getScore` method to your `Team` class:

```
int getScore(){ return this.score;}
```

Then call:

```
teams.sort(Comparator.comparing(Team::getScore));
```

You can reverse the order using:

```
teams.sort(Comparator.comparing(Team::getScore).reversed());
```

One last thing: it is convention that class names begin with a capital letter. You should refactor your `team` class to be `Team`.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they are really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do that without a comparator because you just have Integers to compare to each other:

```
teams.sort((Team t1, Team t2) -> (Integer.compare(t1.getScore(), t2.getScore())));
Collections.reverse(teams);
```