# How to sort ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> in descending order Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort a ArrayList of Strings (descending order) which are in the following format : "row,column".

But since I can't find a way to do that, I thought of converting the ArrayList of Strings into ArrayList<ArrayList> and sorting it in descending order.

For e.g.,

the strings : "21,10", "19,25", "32,5"
will be converted into an ArrayList<ArrayList> like so: [[32,5],[21,10],[19,25]].

NOTE : I only want to sort in descending order based on the first index of inner ArrayList.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned ArrayList<Integers>, while in the description you mention Strings?

Comment: What is the criteria for sorting? Are you sorting in descending order by first element or second element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting ArrayList by specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905802/sorting-arraylist-by-specific-value) or better yet: [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: @GunJack I have added clarifying statements of my original intention and then based on that why I'm trying to descending sort an ArrayList<ArrayList<Interger>>. Please suggest if that is not clear.

Comment: @sorifiend thanks for that link! I think this comment is perfect for my usecase : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905950/9616025.

Unfortunately I don't know enough of Java to understand how to modify that to my use case where I want to use the 0th index element as the comparator. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Dies this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794148/sort-an-arraylist-of-arraylist-of-integers

Comment: @GunJack thanks for the link! How do I reverse this sort? I don't understand that part, I'm a java newbie.

Comment: change `return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));` to `return o2.get(0).compareTo(o1.get(0));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can achieve it with an Arraylist of strings.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("21,10");
list.add("19,25");
list.add("32,5");
```

Once you have your list, you can simply use `Collections.sort()` method.

`Collections.sort(list);`

For reverse order simply add another argument to the sort method.

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Print the list to verify.
`System.out.println(list);`

Here is a running code example.

https://onecompiler.com/java/3y7ahcm6x